# ES6 reduce elements of an array into an array of the frequency of occurence of its elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, reducers

I have an array that contains comma separated numbers in a string, a sample array looks like this

```
const arr = ["2", "1,2", "2,3", "1,3"]
```

I want to create another array which contains the sum of the frequency of occurrence of these values.

Here is the algo I am trying to implement

1. loop through each element, via a reducer that has an accumulator array
2. split each element and convert them into an array of numbers
3. if the accumulator index is empty, initialize it to zero, otherwise add 1, to pre-existing value

Here is the code, I am trying

```
arr.reduce((acc, item) => { 
item.split(",").map((value, index) => {
    val = parseInt(value) 
    acc[val] === null ? acc[val] = 0 : acc[val] += 1 
  })
})
```

I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 2 of undefined`

Comment: I think you're just missing a `(` after the words `reduce` and `map` and the two corresponding `)`s at the end

Comment: you two typos, arr.reduce(acc, item) should be `arr.reduce((acc, item) =>` also `.map(value, index) => {` should be `.map((value, index) => {` and don't forget to add proper closing brackets.

Comment: still gives an error.

Comment: this is a different error now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a default value for the [`accumulator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#Syntax) also I suggest that you use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) instead of using `.map()`, `map()` function used to generate a new array, here you just want to loop through the array, one more thing, you have to return `accumulator` at every iteration.

```js
const arr = ["2", "1,2", "2,3", "1,3"];

let newArr = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item.split(",").forEach((value, index) => {
    val = parseInt(value);
    acc[val] === undefined ? (acc[val] = 0) : (acc[val] += 1);
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: thanks works, any idea, why this is giving error - https://jsfiddle.net/41fqg5dh/

Comment: You missed tacking on the second `{}` in the call to `arr.reduce` in your fiddle, @whatf.

Comment: @Jacob, sorry I didn't get what you mean, did I miss something?

Comment: Was responding to @whatf's question.

Comment: Be careful there, though, because you are relying on abstract equality of `null` and `undefined`. It is better to be explicit and use strict equality `acc[val] === undefined`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli, thanks for pointing that out, I amended my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Although you *can* use map, that's for building a new Array from an existing array. And although you can use a reducer, that's meant for incrementally calculating an accumulator. Since what you're doing instead is just looping over split values you don't need to use map, and since you're *mutating* an end result instead of calculating it, you may want to consider using more performant looping mechanisms that do less of the work that you don't need:

```
const acc = {};
for (const item of arr) {
  for (const value of item.split(",")) {
    val = parseInt(value) 
    acc[val] === null ? acc[val] = 0 : acc[val] += 1 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of issues.

1. you do not provide an initial accumulator.
2. `acc[val]` will be `undefined` not `null` the first time.
3. you need to return the accumulator for the next iteration

so

```js
const arr = ["2", "1,2", "2,3", "1,3"]

const results = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item.split(",").map((value, index) => {
    val = parseInt(value)
    acc[val] === undefined ? acc[val] = 0 : acc[val] += 1
  })
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(results);
```

Comment: your result starts with undefined

Comment: @whatf true,i just changed the accumulator to an object.

Answer (score -2):

```
const arr = ["2", "1,2", "2,3", "1,3"]
var count = {};
arr.reduce((acc, item) => { 
    item.split(",").map((value, index) => {

       if(value in acc) acc[value]++;
       else acc[value] = 1

     })

     return acc;
},count);
```

Result is an object like this {1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 2}